# How to plot the graph shown in the picture?

Tags: python, similarity

I am doing some research in the graph databases. And my interest is to find two similar molecular in the biographical databases called "Mutagenicity". This graph database is very common and contains 4337 graphs modeling chemical molecules. The graphs are undirected and attributed (both vertices and edges). To reduce the number of graph comparisons to be done, few sample graphs are selected and grouped into 8 subsets (Abu-Aisheh et al., 2015a). 
**I want to plot the two graphs when I get their graph ID.** How can I do that? The graph files are as following shown.

**A graph in the graph databases**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
import os
import sys
import fnss
import networkx as nx
import fnss
import cvxopt
import numpy as np
import codecs
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = 'path_to_file.xml'
topology = fnss.read_topology(file)
topology_directed = topology.to_directed(topology)
print(nx.info(topology_directed))
nx.draw(topology_directed)
plt.show()
```